# What would be a regex to match period followed by any number of spaces and then a specific string?

Tags: python

that is, i want to match something like this `.**` , `.    **` , `. **`, etc..

and how do i get that match

Comment: Please add some more clarity details and code what you want to from where? like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
\.\s*\*\*
```

`\.` matches a literal dot.

`\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.

`\*` matches a literal asterisk.